# Could not find driver issue on connecting Microsoft SQL to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, ssms

Connecting SQL Microsoft server management studio 2014 with my laravel application

> could not find driver at /opt/lampp/htdocs/peopledesk-saas/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18, PDOException(code: 0):
> could not find driver at /opt/lampp/htdocs/peopledesk-saas/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:40)

Below is my config/database.php credentials given in my code.

```
'sqlsrv' => [
'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
'host' => 'Server-IP',
'port' => '1433',
'database' => 'database name',
'username' => 'admin',
'password' => 'admin',
'charset' => 'utf8',
'prefix' => '',
],
```

Comment: FYI, SSMS isn't a database engine, and you wouldn't connect your application to it. It's the (R)DBMS you want to connect to, which (in this case) is presumably SQL Server.

Comment: Did you install the sqlsrv PHP module/driver so you can connect to it? Read this, it will tell you how to install it for PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php